# Virtual thread performance in IntSteram vs regular for loop

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, concurrency, virtual-threads

I'm trying to create 100k virtual threads with simple print statements. When I use the below code, the estimated execution time is 2 milliseconds:

```
List < Thread > threads = IntStream.of(0, 100000)
  .mapToObj(it -> Thread.ofVirtual().unstarted(() -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread())))
  .toList();

long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
threads.forEach(Thread::start);
for (Thread thread: threads) {
  thread.join();
}
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("time taken: " + (end - begin) + " milliseconds");
```

But, when I use a `for` loop instead of `IntStream`, the estimated execution time is 6925 milliseconds.

```
List < Thread > threads = new ArrayList < > ();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
  threads.add(Thread.ofVirtual().unstarted(() -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread())));
}

long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
threads.forEach(Thread::start);
for (Thread thread: threads) {
  thread.join();
}
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("time taken: " + (end - begin) + " milliseconds");
```

I know that `IntStream` is more memory efficient than regular `for` loops. But, as per my understanding, `IntStream` doesn't do anything magical compared to a `for` loop.
So, I'm wondering why there's a big gap in the performance above. I'm running this experiment in an 8 core Mac machine.

**Update:**
`IntStream.of()` takes only two numbers above and those are not the range of numbers. So, it is incorrect.

I removed the print statements and used a `HashSet` to track the number of platform threads used. After making the corrections, the estimated execution time to create 100k virtual threads using both `for` loop and `IntStream.range()` is around 150 milliseconds in my 8 core system.

Adding `print` statements added lot of overheads as you can see from previously shared results.

Comment: Add size of threads array to the system out at the end to have an idea what is wrong. To make these two examples equivalent, change `IntStream.of()` to `IntStream.range()`.

Comment: The way you're measuring performance will produce outright lies, but Maciej's point is even more relevant.

Comment: @MaciejWalkowiak
Thanks for point out the mistake there. I was thinking that those are range of numbers!

Comment: @LouisWasserman
I have corrected the mistake as Maciej pointed out. But, otherwise what do you suggest to measure the execution performance? profiling? I will not draw generic conclusion from my 8-core system. The intent here is to evaluate virtual threads in general.

Comment: If you want meaningful performance comparisons, you pretty much _must_ use JMH.  Subtracting System.currentTimeMillis can produce results that are outright wrong even for your system.

Comment: Don’t insert the answer into your question. Post an answer instead.

Comment: @Holger
stackoverflow doesn't let you answer your own question for first 24 hours. You must be knowing it already. And later on, I didn't get time on creating a post here. I will do it.